# Kerberos/Samba can't join Active Directory [DEBIAN 8]

Tags: samba, active-directory, kerberos

I have an issue when I try to join my domain.

I am able to create the kerberos ticket successfully.

```
root@debian:~# kinit Administrateur@ASP.DOMAIN
Password for Administrateur@ASP.DOMAIN:
root@debian:~# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: Administrateur@ASP.DOMAIN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
26/04/2016 18:20:18  27/04/2016 04:20:18  krbtgt/ASP.DOMAIN@ASP.DOMAIN
        renew until 27/04/2016 18:20:11
```

and when I try to join the domain :

```
    root@debian:~# net ads join -k 
Failed to join domain: failed to lookup
    DC info for domain 'ASP.DOMAIN' over rpc: {Device Timeout} The
    specified I/O operation on %hs was not completed before the time-out period expired.
```

my krb5.conf is:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = ASP.DOMAIN

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
        krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
        krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true

[realms]
        ASP.DOMAIN = {
                kdc = asp.domain
                admin_server = server.domain
                default_domain = DOMAIN
        }

[domain_realm]
        .asp.domain = ASP.DOMAIN
        asp.domain = ASP.DOMAIN
```

My smb.conf :

```
[global]
        security = ADS
        realm = ASP.DOMAIN
        password server = server.domain
        workgroup = asp.domain
        winbind separator = /
        idmap uid = 10000-20000
        idmap gid = 10000-20000
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes
        template homedir = /home/%D/%U
        template shell = /bin/bash
        client use spnego = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        domain master = no
        local master = no
        preferred master = no
        os level = 0
```

I have no idea: there is no drop on my firewall. The ticket is ok. I've tried with 3 Domain Controlers.

PS : Domain is a variable

EDIT : I've tried to do it with samba-tool  too

```
root@debian:~# samba-tool domain join ASP.DOMAIN MEMBER -UAdministrateur --real=ASP.DOMAIN
ERROR(runtime): uncaught exception - Connection to SAMR pipe of PDC for ASP.DOMAIN failed: Connection to DC failed: NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 175, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 606, in run
    machinepass=machinepass)
```

EDIT 2 : Join is ok ? But wbinfo -u is not ok

```
root@debian:~# net ads join -U Administrateur
Enter Administrateur's password:
Using short domain name -- DOMAIN
Joined 'ASP.DOMAIN' to dns domain 'asp.domain'
DNS Update for asp.kapia failed: ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR
DNS update failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
root@debian:~# net ads testjoin
Join is OK

root@debian:~# wbinfo -u
could not obtain winbind interface details: WBC_ERR_WINBIND_NOT_AVAILABLE
could not obtain winbind domain name!
Error looking up domain users
```

EDIT 3 :

[image]
EDIT 4 :

```
root@debian:~# service winbind status
● winbind.service - LSB: start Winbind daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/winbind)
   Active: active (exited) since mer. 2016-04-27 16:16:00 CEST; 55s ago
  Process: 2222 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/winbind start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: #5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent.so.0(tevent_common_loop_timer_delay+0xcd) [0x7fbc2b11e1cd]
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: #6 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent.so.0(+0x91ca) [0x7fbc2b11f1ca]
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: #7 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent.so.0(+0x78e7) [0x7fbc2b11d8e7]
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: #8 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtevent.so.0(_tevent_loop_once+0x8d) [0x7fbc2b11a12d]
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: #9 /usr/sbin/winbindd(main+0xb7c) [0x7fbc325cbc8c]
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: #10 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fbc2a92db45]
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: #11 /usr/sbin/winbindd(+0x25318) [0x7fbc325cc318]
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: [2016/04/27 16:16:00.971185,  0] ../source3/lib/dumpcore.c:318(dump_core)
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]: dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/winbindd
avril 27 16:16:00 debian winbindd[2233]:
```

Comment: Can you ping the admin_server defined in your `krb5.conf`? You have the default_realm set there but you might also want to add `dns_lookup_realm = true` and `dns_lookup_kdc = true` in the same `[libdefaults]` section.

Comment: Hi thank you all but i against have issue with your modification.

when i try to join with debut mode, i can see :

`Using short domain name -- DOMAIN
Joined 'ASP.DOMAIN' to dns domain 'asp.domain'
added interface eth0 ip=192.168.1.X bcast=192.168.1.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
ads_dns_lookup_ns: 1 records returned in the answer section.
DNS Update for asp.domain failed: ERROR_DNS_GSS_ERROR
DNS update failed: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
`

Comment: With this command : ` net ads join -U Administrateur -d 5`

Comment: Same error : https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2014-December/187820.html

Comment: I think your server has now joined the domain. (The only error I can see in your update is for DNS.) Please check your Domain Controller and if this is the case I'll create an Answer for you to Accept.

Comment: Ok, sorry, first post :)

Comment: Edit 3 is up ...

Comment: Please check that `/etc/resolv.conf` has a `nameserver` entry that points to your AD domain controller.

Comment: resolv.conf is ok

if stop smbd => restart winbind => start smbd, same issue ...

Comment: Ok, i don't know where but the problem come from the smb.conf

Comment: I would start by fixing winbind. Clearly core dumping in Edit 4.

Comment: Debian 8 is just about old enough that it might still be attempting to use the deprecated SMB v1 protocol by default. Add to the `[global]` section of your `smb.conf` file the `server max protocol =` directive, with the highest value your version of Samba can support (check the smb.conf man page for available values for your version).

Answer (score 0):

You have the `default_realm` set there but you might also want to modify your `krb5.conf` like this:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = ASP.DOMAIN
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
```

I have these entries in my `smb.conf` for `winbind`, but actually I now use `sssd`:

```
winbind trusted domains only = no
winbind use default domain = yes
; winbind enum users = yes            
; winbind enum groups = yes

winbind nested groups = yes
winbind expand groups = 4

winbind offline logon = yes
winbind refresh tickets = yes

winbind normalize names = no
```

The `winbind enum *` settings may slow everything down. Try it and see whether it works well for you, or not. It's one of the reasons I switched to `sssd`.

I find that when joining a Samba client to an AD domain I always get a DNS Update error. The client gets added correctly but just cannot update its DNS entry. (Since the majority of my clients are actually Linux-based servers with static IP addresses this has never bothered me.)

Comment: Thank you again, i've done your modification but same problem for wbinfo (look EDIT2)... just want to authentificate on the server by using Active Directory